# Reading CSV and generating text files with field names read

Tags: perl, csv, parsing, text

I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
Min KTI AD VNA credits per CHA,,,1,Soc/Pac,P-LCC,P-LCC,P-MCC,P-MCC,P-MHCC,P-MHCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,,,,,,,,,
Total K2K AD VNA credits,,,12,Chop/Segment,EP-LCC,EP-LCC,EP-MCC,EP-MCC,EP-MHCC,EP-MHCC,XCC,XCC,EP-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,XCC,,,,,,,,,
Min K2K AD VNA per KTI,,,6,Max KTI,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,,,,,,,,,
Max KTI AD VNA credits shared by IIO,,,4,Active KTI 
Min KTI AD VNA credits per CHA,,,1,Soc/Pac,P-LCC,P-LCC,P-MCC,P-MCC,P-Stops,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,,,,,,,,,
Total K2K BL VNA credits,,,4,Config Name,EP-1S,EP-2S,EP-1S,EP-2S,EP-1S,EP-2S,EP-1S,EP-2S,EP-2S,EX-1S,EX-2S,EX-2S,EX-4S,EX-4S,EX-8S,EX-4S,,,,,,,,,
```

I'm trying to read this file in and generate empty text files that have names like `ep_hcc_2s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e`.

All the `EP-` portions of the CSV become the first part of the text file name, all the numbers followed by an 'S' become the second part of the text file name, followed by `_XXX_lm_por_credits.e` which is appended to the file name.

I'm looking to do this in Perl.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the given sample input? It's unclear what parts of the data should be used.

Comment: @choroba: Transposing this data gives rows like `P-LCC|EP-LCC|2|undef|P-LCC|EP-1S`, and the fourteenth row is `P-HCC|EP-HCC|2|undef|3|EP-2S` which corresponds to the OP's requested output. "Header" row five looks like `Soc/Pac|Chop/Segment|Max KTI|Active KTI|Soc/Pac|Config Name`, so it looks like they want `Chop/Segment` and `Config Name`—columns two and six—munged into a file name.

Comment: @choroba I've not been able to come up with a solution for it yet. I've been able to read the contents of the CSV into an array and as a hash key pair but I've not had any luck with generating the empty text files with correct names..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is very obscure. Not only did you put two line breaks in each line of data, but you didn't explain at all the correspondence between the data and the file names you want

Some detective work reveals that your data seems to be *column-wise*,

Transposing this data gives rows like

```
P-LCC|EP-LCC|2|undef|P-LCC|EP-1S
```

and the fourteenth row is

```
P-HCC|EP-HCC|2|undef|3|EP-2S
```

which corresponds to your requested output. "Header" row five looks like

```
Soc/Pac|Chop/Segment|Max KTI|Active KTI|Soc/Pac|Config Name
```

so it looks like you want `Chop/Segment` and `Config Name`—columns two and six of the transposed data—made into a file name.

That is what this code does

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use List::Util 'max';

# Read and split the data
my @data = map { chomp; [ split /,/ ]; } <DATA>;

# Find the last element of the longest row
my $n = max map { $#$_ } @data;

# Pull out columns two and six of each row and build filename
for my $i ( 0 .. $n ) {

    my @row           = map { $_->[$i] } @data;
    my ($chop, $conf) = @row[1,5];

    next unless $chop and $conf;
    next unless $chop =~ s/^EP\K-/_/ and $conf =~ s/^EP-//;

    my $filename = sprintf '%s_%s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e', map lc, $chop, $conf;
    say $filename;
}


__DATA__
Min KTI AD VNA credits per CHA,,,1,Soc/Pac,P-LCC,P-LCC,P-MCC,P-MCC,P-MHCC,P-MHCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,P-HCC,,,,,,,,,
Total K2K AD VNA credits,,,12,Chop/Segment,EP-LCC,EP-LCC,EP-MCC,EP-MCC,EP-MHCC,EP-MHCC,XCC,XCC,EP-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,EX-HCC,XCC,,,,,,,,,
Min K2K AD VNA per KTI,,,6,Max KTI,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,,,,,,,,,
Max KTI AD VNA credits shared by IIO,,,4,Active KTI 
Min KTI AD VNA credits per CHA,,,1,Soc/Pac,P-LCC,P-LCC,P-MCC,P-MCC,P-Stops,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,,,,,,,,,
Total K2K BL VNA credits,,,4,Config Name,EP-1S,EP-2S,EP-1S,EP-2S,EP-1S,EP-2S,EP-1S,EP-2S,EP-2S,EX-1S,EX-2S,EX-2S,EX-4S,EX-4S,EX-8S,EX-4S,,,,,,,,,
```

#### output

```
ep_lcc_1s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e
ep_lcc_2s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e
ep_mcc_1s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e
ep_mcc_2s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e
ep_mhcc_1s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e
ep_mhcc_2s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e
ep_hcc_2s_XXX_lm_por_credits.e
```

Comment: @Borodin..sorry for the obscure nature of my question. CSV data that I have here is actually the converted format of an excel spreadsheet. Do you think extracting data directly from the spreadsheet would make more sense? Also, I need as many text files as there are valid 'EP-' and numbers followed by 'S' in the data. Correlation would be first 'EP-' picks up the first occurrence of number followed by the 'S'..etc. Hope that made it clearer. Will try out your solution too. Thanks!

Comment: @chmod: No. Excel files are dreadful to read by anything but Excel. Your description matches what my code does.

Comment: @chmod: The file names correspond to columns `Total K2K AD VNA credits` and `Total K2K BL VNA credits`, right?

Comment: yes, that's correct!! The file names match the columns you named. I have all this data in a CSV file. I'm going to pass the CSV file as an input and try out your solution.

Comment: @chmod: Just change `<DATA>` to `<>` and the program will read from a file you name on the command line instead of from the `__DATA__` segment.

Comment: @Borodin..I did that and see the code executing without any errors but it does not do anything..the output file names should get printed on the console or get generated in the same path as the input file, right?

Comment: @chmod: Yes, they will appear on the console. What command line are you using?Try running it against the data in your question (as I have edited it—without the line breaks). Or show in your question the first dozen or so lines of the data you're using.

Comment: @Borodin..yup that works! One more question though: My actual data looks exactly like the one I've posted here, just that it is much much bigger (several lines of CSV)..is this logic limited in any way to just this chunk of data? Or is the array structure unable to expand to the large data I have?

Comment: @chmod: It will look through those two columns in every line of the file for `EP-` values. It should be fine unless those two `Total K2K` columns are not columns two and six.